# XStream serialize custom Map with NamedMapConverter

Tags: java, android, xstream

I am successfully serializing my `Base` class containing `HashMap<String, String>` with `NamedMapConverter`. My requirements have changed and I need to change `HashMap` to custom `StringDictionary` class that extends `HashMap<String, String>`.

But after using `StringDictionary`, my serialization got broken. Is there a way to configure `XStream` and/or `NamedMapConverter` to preserve needed `xml` output without writing custom converters?

Using XStream 1.4.7 on Android.

---

Required `xml` output:

```
<base>
  <values>
    <val key="123">111</val>
    <val key="abc">aaa</val>
  </values>
</base>
```

`Base` class with `HashMap` and `XStream` configuration that produces above output

```
public class Base
{
    public Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
}


Base base = new Base();
base.values.put("abc", "aaa");
base.values.put("123", "111");

XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("base", Base.class);
NamedMapConverter c = new NamedMapConverter(xs.getMapper(), "val", "key", String.class, null, String.class, true, false, xs.getConverterLookup());
xs.registerConverter(c);

String s = xs.toXML(base);
```

---

Using modified `Base` class

```
public class Base
{
    public Map<String, String> values = new StringDictionary();
}
```

produces following incorrect `xml` output:

```
<base>
  <values class="com.test.StringDictionary" serialization="custom">
    <unserializable-parents/>
    <map>
      <default>
        <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
      </default>
      <int>4</int>
      <int>2</int>
      <string>123</string>
      <string>111</string>
      <string>abc</string>
      <string>aaa</string>
    </map>
  </values>
</base>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that without custom converter above is impossible to achieve. However, in this case custom converter can be provided with only slight tweaking of existing one. Problem lies in `NamedMapConverter.canConvert` method that has to be overridden to include custom `StringDictionary` class.

Following code will produce required `xml` output for modified `Base` class:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("base", Base.class);

xs.addDefaultImplementation(StringDictionary.class, Map.class);
NamedMapConverter c = new NamedMapConverter(xs.getMapper(), "val", "key", String.class, null, String.class, true, false, xs.getConverterLookup())
{
    public boolean canConvert(Class type)
    {
        if (type.equals(StringDictionary.class)) return true;
        else return super.canConvert(type);
    }
};
xs.registerConverter(c);
```

---

Another simpler (but not fully compliant) solution, is to pass `StringDictionary` class to `NamedMapConverter` constructor. However this solution will slightly change `xml` output.

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("base", Base.class);
NamedMapConverter c = new NamedMapConverter(StringDictionary.class, xs.getMapper(), "val", "key", String.class, null, String.class, true, false, xs.getConverterLookup());
xs.registerConverter(c);


<base>
  <values class="com.test.StringDictionary">
    <val key="123">111</val>
    <val key="abc">aaa</val>
  </values>
</base>
```