# How to change name of root element in map to xml conversion with xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I'm converting map to xml using XStream's NamedMapConverter but the root element is always `<map>`.
I cannot find a way to change it. Is it possible and how?

Comment: In this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296215/xstream-serialize-custom-map-with-namedmapconverter, there is a `XStream xs = new XStream(); xs.alias("base", Base.class);`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Also, you need put some more code to people help you, check that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why don't you use Jackson instead. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941479/jaxb-how-to-marshall-map-into-keyvalue-key

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems the only thing that's needed to change the root tag name is set
`xStream.alias("your_root_tag_name", Map.class);`